# Argument X passed to Y must be an instance of boolean, boolean given - PHP7

Tags: php, types, php-7, type-hinting

Given code

```
<?php
function a(boolean $value){
    var_dump($value);
}
a(true);
```

I receive error

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to a() must be an instance of boolean, boolean given

What is going on here?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Only valid typehint for `boolean` is `bool`. As per [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration) `boolean` isn't recognized as alias of `bool` in typehints. Instead it is treated as class name. 
Same goes for `int`(scalar) and `integer`(class name), which will result in error

> TypeError: Argument 1 passed to a() must be an instance of integer, integer given

In this specific case object of class `boolean` is expected but `true`(bool, scalar) is passed.

Valid code is

```
<?php
function a(bool $value){
    var_dump($value);
}
a(true);
```

which result is

> bool(true)